# Get возвращает неверную кодировку от обработчика PHP

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Проблема в следующем
Есть форма авторизации. При ошибке(неверный логин или пароль) обработчик возвращает ту самую ошибку( что конкретно не так) и возвращает в кракозябрах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все в UTF-8 (клиент, сервер, htaccess, meta charset, кодировка файлов UTF-8 without BOM, база данных тоже, хотя данные оттуда даже не ипользуються в ответе)
Перепробовал все в итоге приходит GET такой

```
?message=ÐÐµÐ²ÐµÑÐ½ÑÐ¹%20Ð¿Ð°ÑÐ¾Ð»Ñ
```

Подскажите, что может быть? Причем проверяю кодировку через mb_detect_encode - везде пишет UTF-8

Код Функции

```
public function auth($post){
            $data = $this->clearData($post);
            $data['login'] = strtolower($data['login']);
            $query="SELECT id, password, checked FROM users WHERE login = '$data[login]'";
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            $result = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if(!$result['password']) $str= "Профиль с таким логином не найден";
            
            $data['password'] = md5($data['password']);
            if($data['password']===$result['password']){
                if(!$result['checked']) $str = "Профиль не подтвержден. Обратитесь к администратору.";
                $_SESSION['user']['id']  = $result['id'];
                setcookie('userId', $result[id], time()+2592000*12);
            }
            else $str =  "Неверный пароль";
            return $str;
        }
```

Comment: Добавлю. Ответ отправляю через header. Код контроллера:
case 'auth':
    $result = $page->auth($_POST);
    header('Location:'.$page->base_url."?message=$result");
                exit;
    break;

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Не выставили кодировку для ответа, выше подсказали

Comment: @u_mulder Нет. Дело не в этом. Но для ясности покажу код страницы ответа
`<?php
require_once('lib/controller.php');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: @u_mulder
Кстати, 
`var_dump(headers_list())` выводит следующее `array(5) { [0]=> string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29" [1]=> string(38) "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT" [2]=> string(77) "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" [3]=> string(16) "Pragma: no-cache" [4]=> string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" }`